# Uniquely encode any ASCII string into a string that uses a subset of ASCII

Tags: python, string, encoding, ascii, decoding

For this question, please assume python, but it doesn't necessarily matter.

Imagine you have an arbitrary ASCII string, for example:

```
jrioj4oi3m_=\.,ei9#
```

Sparing the extensive details, I need to pass this string as a "label" on to another program, but that program doesn't support "labels" containing "special characters" or even numbers. So I'm trying to encode an ASCII string into a string that uses an arbitrary subset of ASCII.

One very naive solution would be to convert the original string into binary, then convert 0s into "a" and 1s into "b". This works to solve my problem, but I would like to learn a better solution here, to become a better programmer.

First of all, what exactly is this problem called?

This is not exactly a hashing problem, because IIRC hashing generally involves encoding into a string that is shorter than the original, and involves collisions.

I need *no* collisions, and I don't really care how long the encoded string is, as long as it's shorter than the naive case. (Ideally it would be the shortest length possible given the subset)

In fact, it would be ideal to specify exactly what the allowed character set is, then use a generalized encoding algorithm to do the encoding.

Decoding would be nice to know also.

Comment: You could view your input as numbers in Base-N (N being 128 if you allow the full range of ASCII characters and less than that if you restrict your input further) and the output as Base-M (M being the number of allowed characters for your labels). That's the basic idea behind the Base64 encoding (with N being 256 and M being 64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to first convert to a hex encoding:

- `jrioj4oi3m_=.,ei9#` => `6a72696f6a346f69336d5f3d2e2c65693923`

and then translate any numbers into non-hex letters:

- `6a72696f6a346f69336d5f3d2e2c65693923` => `waxswzwfwatuwfwzttwdvftdsescwvwztzst`

So the output string would always be exactly twice the length of the input string and only ever contain characters in the range a-z.

This can be easily achieved in python like this:

```
>>> enc = str.maketrans('0123456789', 'qrstuvwxyz')
>>> dec = str.maketrans('qrstuvwxyz', '0123456789')
>>> s = 'jrioj4oi3m_=.,ei9#'
>>> x = s.encode('ascii').hex().translate(enc)
>>> x
'waxswzwfwatuwfwzttwdvftdsescwvwztzst'
>>> bytes.fromhex(x.translate(dec)).decode('ascii')
'jrioj4oi3m_=.,ei9#'
```

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, this actually turns out to be a really simple and common math problem: Base conversion. As a programmer, you probably know, at least in theory, how to convert between base 2, 10, and 16 representations of a value.  There are 96 printable ASCII characters, so any ASCII string can be considered to be a base 96 representation of a (probably very large) value.  If your label only accepts 64 characters (uppercase, lowercase, digits, and 2 others, for instance), then you simply need to convert your base 96 representation into a base 64 representation of the same value.
Decoding is simply converting your base 64 representation back to the base 96 representation.